# Cimbalino appbar, blinking while changing pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, cimbalino

Every time, when i'm navigating to the page with minimized appbar, or to the page without appbar, i see weird blinking at the bottom of the page.

First page is like this
[image]

But when transaction starts, i see black background
[image]

And its lasts during all transaction
[image]

How to set that background to white?

EDIT: tried to set appbar's opacity.. well, sometimes it works, but sometimes not. I have it like this

```
<Grid>
****
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <cimbalino:ApplicationBarBehavior>
            <cimbalino:ApplicationBarIconButton 
                Click="MyEvent"
                IconUri="/Resources/Icons/appbar.add.png"
                Text="{Binding Path=MainResources.Add, Source={ StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
        </cimbalino:ApplicationBarBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>



<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar 
        Opacity="0.99"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource OurBestColor}"
        ForegroundColor="Black">
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: I think you should contact the author of the library. It is not widely use as far as I know so your chances are slim that anyone else will be able to help you

Comment: @IgorKulman Yep, he contacted me several times on stackoverflow. But is there any better appbar, which supports smooth transaction animation and per-pivotitem definition?

Comment: I've seen that behavior a few times... let me see if I can figure how to fix that!

Comment: @PedroLamas Great, thanks! Steps to reproduce: just navigate from the page with normal appbar to the page with minimized appar (or to the page without appbar).

Comment: @PedroLamas Any news on this field?

Comment: I've managed to mimic the problem on a sample code, seems it's related to having a background color different than the one from the active theme... I don't think there is a workaround this, rather than just setting the AppBar opacity to something != 1.0

Comment: @PedroLamas Well.. sorry for long answer. It took lots of time to figure out, if it fixes or not. It seems that i still have that blinking, even with opacity appbar. See question edit.